# yandex-maps-api определяет страну, но не определяет регион

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карта-api

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<form>
    <input type="hidden" class="country" name="loc_country" />
    <input type="hidden" class="region" name="loc_region" />
    <input type="hidden" class="city" name="loc_city" />
</form>
```

Может быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался? Страна определяется в каждой заявке. Город - не в каждой (в том случае, когда населенный пункт мелкий). Но отчего может не определяться регион (например, область)? Такие заявки редко, но приходят.

Comment: Это архивная версия API, вам стоит использовать актуальную 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Как верно заметили в комментарии, используемая вами для геолокации версия API Яндекс.Карт уже архивная. Хотя в вашем сценарии её могло и хватать (с возможными нарушениями [пользовательского соглашения](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/)), поддержки и исправления возможных ошибок и недочётов ждать в данном случае от Яндекса уже не стоит.

Посмотрите, как реализована геолокация в актуальной версии 2.1 JS API и попробуйте применить её в своём проекте:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation